# The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using Cauchy's Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand [wiki's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra):

It says that the number of zeros of $p(z)$ (with degree $n$) is given by $N=$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c(r)} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz$$

but why do I need to consider the function $n/z$? What is it? Then they take the difference:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c(r)} (\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} - \frac{n}{z}) dz$$ and show that this goes to $0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$.

Knowing that $N-n=0$ we conclude that $N=n\Rightarrow P(z)$ has $n$ zeros

**My questions are:**

1)What is $n/z$

2)Why does the numerator of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} - \frac{n}{z}$ have degree $n-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof considers $\frac{n}{z}$ because $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c(r)} \frac{n}{z} dz = n$.

The numerator of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} - \frac{n}{z}$ is $zp'(z)-np(z)$. It has degree at most $n-1$ because $zp'(z)$ and n$p(z)$ have the same leading term: $n a_n z^n$.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Comment: Just a remark, the closed integral is always 0, unless the denominator has degree 1 more than the numerator. Because that is when we have singularities?